# Vim swap and backup files for encrypted drive

Tags: vim

I like setting the swap and backup directories to the temp directory just to keep them out of the way.  E.g.

```
set backup
set directory=C:/Temp//
set backupdir=C:/Temp//
```

However, I have some files on a TrueCrypt drive (my "T:" drive).  When I use Vim to modify those files, I'd like it to keep the swap and backup files on the same (T:) drive, or else not create swap and backup files at all.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As I was typing this question, I thought of a possible answer.  Alternative answers welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just make sure there's a Temp directory at the root of the encrypted drive:

```
set backup
set directory=/Temp//,C:/Temp//
set backupdir=/Temp//,C:/Temp//
```

If there isn't one, it will fall back to the Temp directory on the C drive.